# Use shared 404 page for virtual hosts in Nginx

Tags: nginx, virtualhost, http-status-code-404

I'd like to have a shared 404 page to use across my virtual hosts.  The following is my setup.

Two sites, each with their own config file in /sites-available/ and /sites-enabled/

1. www.foo.com
2. bar.foo.com

The www directory is set up as:

```
www/
foo.com/
foo.com/index.html
bar.foo.com/
bar.foo.com/index.html
shared/
shared/404.html
```

Both config files in /sites-available are the same except for the root and server name:

```
root /var/www/bar.foo.com;
index index.html index.htm index.php;

server_name bar.foo.com;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}
error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root /var/www/shared;
}
```

I've tried the above code and also tried setting `error_page 404 /var/www/shared/404.html` (without the following location block).

I've also double checked to make sure my permissions are set to 775 for all folders and files in www.

When I try to access a non-existent page, Nginx serves the respective index.php of the virtual host I'm trying to access.

Can anyone point out what I'm doing wrong?  Thanks!

Comment: http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#try_files

Comment: Not sure I understand.  Is there something wrong with the try_files line?  It should only serve index.php if I try to visit a directory.  If I try to visit http://www.foo.com/doesnotexist.html, it shouldn't return index.php.  If I remove the last location block after error_page and move 404.html into one of the site folders, it correctly return the 404 page.

Comment: _Note that you can specify an HTTP `status` code as the last argument to try_file since Nginx version 0.7.51._

Comment: But that would conflict with the index.php catch so if someone tried to visit foo.com/ they'd either get the a 404 page or index.php with a 404 code.

Comment: Have you tried this yet?

Comment: I tried try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php /var/www/shared/404.html =404; and try_files $uri $uri/ /var/www/shared/404.html =404;.  Both of them just served index.php and tried to download the page if if specified a .html extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
error_page 404 /404.html;
location = /404.html {
    root /var/www/shared;
}
```